# Python lambda is not Getting Variables From Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to get which button was clicked within for loop but i can't able to get button inside the function and the button is generated by for loop and code is this:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.create_grid()

    def create_grid(self):
        for i in range(1, 4):
            self.btn= ttk.Button(self, text="", command=lambda btn=self.btn: self.clik(btn))
            self.btn.grid(ipadx=20, ipady=20, row=i, column=0)


    def clik(self, btn):
        print(btn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
    self.btn= ttk.Button(self, text="", command=lambda btn=self.btn: self.clik(btn))
  File "fakepath\__init__.py", line 2346, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'btn'
```

Thanks For Any Help.

Comment: command in separate line `self.btn.configure(command=lambda btn=self.btn: self.clik(btn))`

Comment: You could also `from functools import partial` and then `self.btn.config(command=partial(self.click, self.btn))` (obviously place the import at the beginning of the code)

Comment: @Matiiss Hey! it also works grate but what is going inside?

Comment: As far as I understand it just returns a function with the given arguments so that it will run with those arguments every time, basically the same as with the lambda function just shorter and probably has other uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, the RHS of an *assignment* is first evaluated and then it stores the value in LHS or so. Here if you notice:

```
self.btn= ttk.Button(self, text="", command=lambda btn=self.btn: self.clik(btn))
```

`self.btn` is only defined after the RHS of this line is evaluated, but inside this line itself you are referencing to the `self.btn`, which is not defined(yet). Hence the error of not having an attribute `btn`. So what you can do is assign the command in the next line:

```
self.btn = ttk.Button(self, text="")
self.btn['command'] = lambda btn=self.btn: self.clik(btn)
```

Comment: can you join disuccsion?

Comment: @TangerCity I do not have the link, you should tag me in it.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232816/discussion